# Joining on table value in database

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a table that holds a relationship of the id to the actual name of the joining table, I need to be able to get the actual table name out with an ID value. example:

```
TableID    TableName
1          Test.Customers
2          Test.Orders
3          Test.Addresses
```

So to be able to pass in the ID of 1 and come back with "Customers" and to be able to use that to "SELECT * FROM Customers".  What's the best approach to do this?  What would that stored procedure look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Dynamic SQL, Like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc (@ID int)
AS

DECLARE @SQL Varchar(1000) = ''

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TableName)
FROM MyLookupTable
WHERE TableID = @ID

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Be **very very very** careful with Dynamic SQL, [and read this before proceeding.](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)